# Navigation bar in Processing for bigger than screen drawing

Tags: navigation, drawing, processing, real-time

I'm having trouble moving the perspective in a 10000 pixel wide window, in which I am performing a drawing every millisecond or so, and all the drawings are stacking in the x direction. I want to be able to move the perspective that is shown on my screen along the x axis where I want it to, so that i can see the real time drawing happening.

I am using the light sensor on an Arduino-type board to communicate to the PDE the light levels, and I am drawing a Bezier curve for each instance of the light read, making the Bezier wider when the light is dim, and narrower when the light is intense.

[image: The Beziers covering all the screen allready]

I am trying to implement a navigator bar of this type:

```java
    void setup()
{
  size(1800, 1800);
}

void draw()
{ int x_navigator = width / 2 - width / 6, y_navigator = 80, navigator_width = width / 3, navigator_height = 40;
  fill(204);
  rect(x_navigator, y_navigator, navigator_width, navigator_height);
  fill(250, 204, 0, 160);
  if (mouseX > x_navigator && mouseY > y_navigator && mouseX < x_navigator + navigator_width && mouseY < y_navigator + navigator_height)
  {
    if (mouseX < x_navigator + navigator_width / 12)
    {
      rect(x_navigator, y_navigator, navigator_width / 6, navigator_height);
    }
    else
    {
      if (mouseX > x_navigator + ((11 * navigator_width) / 12))
      {
        rect(x_navigator + (5 * navigator_width) / 6, y_navigator, navigator_width / 6, navigator_height);
      }
      else
      {
        rect(mouseX - (navigator_width / 12), y_navigator, navigator_width / 6, navigator_height);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

on my code that draws Beziers:

```java
import processing.serial.*;

Serial Engduino;
String light_String = "", temperature_String = "";
int constant = 300;
float begin_x = 0, begin_y = 550, end_x, end_y, control = 1, light, temperature;

    void setup()
    {
      String portName = "COM3";
      Engduino = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);
      size(1000, 800);
      noFill();
      smooth();
      strokeWeight(3);
    }

    void draw()
    {
      if (Engduino.available() > 0) 
      {
        light_String = Engduino.readStringUntil('\n');
        try{light = parseFloat(light_String);}
        catch(NullPointerException e)
        {;}
        println("The light is: ");
        println(light);
        end_x = begin_x + (400 / (sqrt(light) + 1));
        end_y = begin_y - constant;
        control = end_x - begin_x;
        bezier(begin_x, begin_y, begin_x + control, begin_y, end_x - control, end_y, end_x, end_y);
        constant = constant * (-1);
        begin_x = end_x;
        begin_y = end_y;
      }
    }
```

While making it functional as to move the displayed image where the cursor is, so that I can see the drawing in real time, and also to check the previous curves drawn if I so wish.

EDIT: So the code that works without an Engduino is this:

```java
int constant = 300;
float begin_x = 0, begin_y = 550, end_x, end_y, control = 1, light = 30; // Light is what I get through the serial port from the Engduino (an Arduino type board`)

void setup()
{
  size(10000, 800); // The 10000-pixel wide window.
  noFill();
  smooth();
  strokeWeight(3);
}

void draw()
{
    end_x = begin_x + (400 / (sqrt(light) + 1));
    end_y = begin_y - constant;
    control = end_x - begin_x;
    bezier(begin_x, begin_y, begin_x + control, begin_y, end_x - control, end_y, end_x, end_y);
    constant = constant * (-1);
    begin_x = end_x;
    begin_y = end_y;
}
```

What I want is to have a navigation bar of the type I've shown (at least in design) to navigate around the 10000-pixel wide window. The navigation bar code I have uploaded is only a design of the navigation, and has no functionality, that's where I want some help.

Comment: You'll have better luck if you post a [mcve] that doesn't rely on the serial library. Just use a hardcoded drawing so we can copy and paste your code to run it. You also haven't told us what the problem is. What do you expect this code to do? What does it do instead? Have you tried narrowing it down to a specific line of code that's behaving differently from what you expect?

Comment: Sure, I will post an edit soon.

Comment: I've posted the edit and I have specified the problem.

Comment: Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to be a little complicated just because your drawing is done over multiple frames. You're not clearing the canvas every frame, you're building up a drawing over time.

If you were clearing the canvas and redrawing everything each frame (which is what many Processing sketches do), then you could simply change the `X` value of where you're drawing everything, or simply call the `translate()` function before drawing everything else.

But since you're drawing everything over multiple frames, you're going to have to draw to a `PGraphics` buffer. Then on each frame, you draw the buffer using whatever X offset you want. Here's a little example:

```
int constant = 300;
float begin_x = 0, begin_y = 550, end_x, end_y, control = 1, light = 30; // Light is what I get through the serial port from the Engduino (an Arduino type board`)

PGraphics pg;

void setup()
{
  size(10000, 800); // The 10000-pixel wide window.
  pg = createGraphics(width, height);
}

void draw()
{

  end_x = begin_x + (400 / (sqrt(light) + 1));
  end_y = begin_y - constant;
  control = end_x - begin_x;

  pg.beginDraw();
  pg.noFill();
  pg.smooth();
  pg.strokeWeight(3);
  pg.bezier(begin_x, begin_y, begin_x + control, begin_y, end_x - control, end_y, end_x, end_y);
  pg.endDraw();

  constant = constant * (-1);
  begin_x = end_x;
  begin_y = end_y;

  background(200);
  image(pg, -mouseX, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I would like to ask a few more questions to make sure I understood the concept well. First of all, this graphics buffer does display the data in real time? The word "buffer" makes me think of a waiting time. Also, the buffer is a rectangle and all that it contains? Should I get all the functions the were called a single time in the setup to be called all the time in the draw now? i'm talking about noFill(), smooth()...

Comment: @AndreiBarbu I'd recommend checking out [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/PGraphics.html) first. But the word "buffer" just means that your'e drawing to something other than the screen first (which you're already doing without a buffer, Processing just hides that from you). It doesn't mean anything about waiting times. If you still have follow-up questions, I suggest asking them in their own posts with an updated [mcve]. Good luck!